# Dudeney's "Modern Puzzles" - number 38, The Despatch-Rider

Tags: word-problem

In Henry Ernest Dudeney's "Modern Puzzles" of 1926 (now out of print) we have:

38. The Despatch-Rider

If an army forty miles long advances forty miles while a despatch-rider gallops from the rear to the front, delivers a depatch to the commanding general, and returns to the rear, how far has he to travel?

My solution is that it seems clear that the rider goes twice as fast as the army, so he goes 80 miles one way and 2/3 of 40 miles the other, being an obvious 19 1/3 miles.

But Dudeney's solution is:

"The answer is the square root of twice the square of 40, added to 40. This is $96.568$ miles, or, roughly $96 \tfrac 1 2$ miles."

Anybody got any idea how he arrives at this?

Comment: Remember that the rider’s *relative* speed with respect to the army differs for each leg because the army is advancing while he’s riding.  The first leg is surely shorter than $80$ miles because the army hasn’t advanced the full $40$ miles by the time the rider completes the first leg so your answer can’t be right.

Comment: Why is it clear that the rider goes twice as fast as the army? If he does, then the army will have arrived at their destination by the time the rider has reached the front. If I'm interpreting the problem correctly, the army only reaches its destination once the rider has made it all the way back to the rear once more.

Comment: What I'd assume is that the dispatch finishes his task at the same time the last soldier in line has marched 40 miles. Let $y$ be such that  $y+40$ is the distance from the dispatch to his starting position at the time when he meets the general. From this momment, the time it takes the last guy to end his march is the same as the time it takes the dispatch to end his. Using this observation (and the observation that $40+2y=x\cdot40$ if the speed of the dispatch is $x$  miles per minute and the march proceeds at 1 mile per minute), I arrived at the author's figure ($40+40\sqrt2$).

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you, that was my misunderstanding. I had misinterpreted the question such that I had assumed that the army had travelled 40 miles while the rider had merely travelled to the front. I had not twigged that the 40 miles travelled included the time he returned to the rear again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach:

Assume that the army's length is $(40)$.

Assume that the rider's speed is $(r > 1)$ while the army's speed is $1$.

Assume that the first leg of the trip uses time $t_1.$

Assume that the second leg of the trip uses time $t_2.$

The distance traveled by the rider is $r(t_1 + t_2)$.

Further, from the problem's constraints, 
$40 = (1) \times (t_1 + t_2) \implies (t_1 + t_2) = 40.$

Therefore, the problem is reduced to computing $r$.

---

During $t_1$, the speed at which the rider covers the $(40)$ is (in effect) $(r - 1)$.

During $t_2$, the speed at which the rider covers the $(40)$ is (in effect) $(r + 1)$.

Therefore, $t_1(r - 1) = 40 = t_2(r + 1).$

Therefore $40 = t_1 + t_2 = \displaystyle \frac{40}{r-1} + \frac{40}{r+1}.$

This implies that $1 = \displaystyle \frac{1}{r-1} + \frac{1}{r+1} = \frac{2r}{r^2 - 1}$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle r^2 - 2r - 1 = 0 \implies r = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \times \left[2 \pm \sqrt{8}\right] = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}$.

Since $r$ must be $> 0$, (in fact $r$ must be $> 1$), you have that $r = 1 + \sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_{0}$ be the length of the army in miles (in this problem, $x_{0}=40$). Assume the army is travelling along the $x$-axis, with the rear of the army starting at $0$, the front of the army starting at $x_{0}$. Assume without loss of generality that at time $1$, the despatch-rider has finished (so the front of the army has reached position $2x_{0}$ and the despatch-rider is at position $x_{0}$, the back of the army).

Let $t_{0}$ be the time at which the despatch-rider reached the front of the army (after which point he reverses direction), and let $m$ be the speed of the despatch-rider. Then we have the following facts:

- the position of the front of the army at time $t$ is $x_{0} + x_{0}t$ for $0\le t \le 1$
- position of the despatch-rider at time $t$ is $mt$ for $0\le t \le t_{0}$ and $-mt+b$ for $t_{0}\le t \le 1$, where $m$ is the constant speed of the despatch rider, and $b$ is a constant to be determined.

We can find $m, b, t_{0}$ in terms of known quantities. Then the distance travelled by the despatch-rider will be $m$ (as he travels at speed $m$ for time $1$).

From the second bullet point above, we must have
$$mt_{0} = -mt_{0}+b \Rightarrow 2mt_{0} - b = 0. \tag{1}$$

Also, since the despatch-rider is at position $x_{0}$ at time $1$, the second bullet point implies that
$$-m+b = x_{0}.\tag{2}$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives $(2t_{0}-1)m = x_{0}\Rightarrow m = \frac{x_{0}}{2t_{0} - 1}$.

So $(1)$ implies that $b = 2t_{0}m = \frac{2t_{0}x_{0}}{2t_{0}-1}$.

Now, the first bullet point above implies that $x_{0}+x_{0}t_{0} = -mt_{0}+b$ (i.e. at time $t_{0}$ the head of the army and the despatch-rider are at the same position). So we have

$$\begin{align}
x_{0} + x_{0}t_{0} &= -mt_{0}+b\\
\Rightarrow x_{0} + x_{0}t_{0} &= -\frac{x_{0}t_{0}}{2t_{0} - 1} + \frac{2t_{0}x_{0}}{2t_{0}-1} \\
\Rightarrow 1 + t_{0} &= \frac{t_{0}}{2t_{0} - 1}\\
\Rightarrow (2t_{0} - 1)(1 + t_{0}) &= t_{0} \\
\Rightarrow 2t_{0} + 2t_{0}^{2} - 1 - t_{0} &= t_{0} \\ 
\Rightarrow 2t_{0}^{2} &= 1 \\
\Rightarrow t_{0} &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.
\end{align}$$

So $m = \frac{x_{0}}{2t_{0} - 1} = \frac{x_{0}}{\sqrt{2}-1} = \left(\sqrt{2} + 1\right)x_{0}$.

Hence the distance travelled by the despatch-rider is $m = \left(\sqrt{2} + 1\right)x_{0}$. In your particular problem, since $x_{0}$ is $40$ miles, the total distance travelled by the despatch-rider is $\left(\sqrt{2} + 1\right)\times 40 \approx 96.57$ miles.